# No Window Displayed by Tkinter in VSCode

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, tkinter

I'm trying to make a GUI application with tkinter in vscode but when I run my program I don't get a window.

My code is as follows:

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
greeting = Label(text="Hello, World")

greeting.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Running tkinter with just Python in the command line works, but not when I try in vscode. Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: Have you set a Python interpreter in VS Code? What happens if you run the command `python -m tkinter` from VS Code?

Comment: @JRiggles Terminal moves to a new line without a cursor. Which is the same as when I run the program. It's acting like it's running something and waiting for input.

Comment: Does a tkinter window open up somewhere? That command should start a very basic tk app. The same should be true for your app - when you run it in VS Code, the app window should open. Check your taskbar for any new windows.

Comment: @JRiggles I've checked my taskbar and task manager and nothing is there.

Comment: If you run that command in a regular Command Prompt, does the example app show up?

Comment: Yes. Using the basic python Command Line by just running python on my PC works fine, The problem only occurs in VSCode.

Comment: Are you using the "Run" button in VS Code, or something else?

Comment: I've used the run button, I've run with the python command in the terminal, and I've run with the debugger

Comment: Hrmm...are VS Code and the Python extension both up to date? Perhaps try reinstalling the Python extension? Sorry friend, I'm grasping at straws a bit.

Comment: Haha no worries, I appreciate your time. Yes, everything has been updated recently, I even reinstalled VSCode. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: Ah darn. Sorry I couldn't help more - I'll let ya know if I think of anything